# PSTCollectionview is not working for me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, collectionview, pstcollectionview

I have one storyboard project in that i added PSTCollectionview classes and all files .Then i created one class for my viewcontroller "allbooks.h,.m in "PSUICollectionviewcontroller_" and iam not able to add this class on my viewcontroller ??? please

**GMMAllBooksGrid.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GMMAllBooksGrid : PSUICollectionViewController
@end
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Try explaining in more detail.  Try editing your post to include the contents of allbooks.h.

Comment: You have to add PSTCollectionView programmatically show ur code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **PSTCollectionView** in the same way as **UICollectionView**. I will post my code may help you.

**CollectionViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PSTCollectionView.h"


@interface CollectionViewController : UIViewController <PSUICollectionViewDataSource,PSUICollectionViewDelegate,PSUICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property(nonatomic,retain) PSUICollectionView *collectionView;
@end
```

**CollectionViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadView
{
[super loadView];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
PSUICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[PSUICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

// Configure layout attributes globally
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(150, 150);

self.collectionView = [[[PSUICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)) collectionViewLayout:layout]autorelease];
[self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
[self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
[self.collectionView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
[self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// Register Cell and supplimentary views
[self.collectionView registerClass:[PSUICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];



[self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
}
```